# How do I pass a ViewModel to an Edit Action in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass a `ViewModel` to an Edit Action in MVC4, I've created for the `Create` action but like a beginner I'm stuck here.

```
public class EditEntryViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? entryId)
    {
        Entry customer = _db.Entries.Single(x => x.Id == entryId);
        var customerViewModel = new EditEntryViewModel();
        return View(customerViewModel);
     }
```

**Entry class:**

```
public class Entry
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Does the above code not work?

Comment: I'm trying to edit fields, but with this code in HttpGet is not displaying my edit fields from the view. I've updated now to       var model = _db.Entries.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == entryId);  return View(model); it have the fields but they are empty, without data.

Comment: Can you add the code of `Entry` class?

Comment: Your creating a new instance of `EditEntryViewModel` but not setting any properties. I assume you want to map the properties from `customer ` to `EditEntryViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting any properties of `customerViewModel`, so your view doesn't display any data. Based on the `Entry` class definition, here's what your controller action method should look like

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? entryId)
{
    var customerViewModel = new EditEntryViewModel();

    if (entryId.HasValue)
    {
        Entry customer = _db.Entries.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == entryId.Value);
        if (customer != null)
        {
            customerViewModel.Title = customer.Title;
            customerViewModel.Username = customer.Username;
            customerViewModel.Password = customer.Password;
            customerViewModel.Url = customer.Url;
            customerViewModel.Description = customer.Description;
        }
    }

    return View(customerViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Now have error: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: Entry customer = _db.Entries.Single(x => x.Id == entryId);

Comment: Please try the updated answer, also make sure you use this url: `Edit/x` where x is the id of `Entry`, not just `Edit`

Comment: Since `.SingleOrDefault()` can return `null` you should test for this before setting the values.

Comment: it will still throw null reference exception when `customer` is `null`

Comment: Just edited the answer, thanks @StephenMuecke and `Ehsan Sajjad` for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The action you posted is for display the edit page, what you need to do with it is only call it with the id parameter and it is not asked for the complete view model

Guess you are going to save the edit result?

Create another action with the same name, but accept `EditEntryViewModel` with the parameter and accept `[HttpPost]` only

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditEntryViewModel viewModel)
{
//code here  
}
```

Comment: The OP only said `im stuck here`, it's not clear what the problem is.